# react-beautiful-dnd will not compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app, react-beautiful-dnd

I have had react-beautiful-dnd installed and functional for a while and out of nowhere I am now getting an error from node_modules about create-react-app being unable to compile the file position.js in the react-beautiful-dnd package. I have looked into breaking changes being pushed to their repo but nothing is different 2 months back, I invalidated my cache and restarted (on webstorm) nothing, finally I deleted my node_modules and reinstalled them but still the error occurs.

[image]

[image]

It seems to be rightly trying to compile the file as javascript given its extension  however the code seems to be Typescript, I looked at the repository and indeed github reports it to be 100% javascript but most of the files I saw including the snipped above seem to use Typescript. I was under the impression that typescript could not be directly run from a javascript file am I incorrect? What could be causing the error?

Thank you

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: the `// @flow` indicate that Flow typing system. Make sure you have add Flow support to your CRA https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-flow/

Comment: Why are these steps not listed on the react-beautiful-dnd npm install page if they are needed?

Answer (score 1):

To use `import type`, you should place `type` before the curly brackets:

```js
import type { Position } from 'css-box-model';
```

Besides, if you want to import the type definition in `'css-box-model'` as well as its methods or constants, [import them separately](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/consistent-type-imports.md):

```js
import { constant } from 'css-box-model';
import type { interface } from 'css-box-model';
```

Comment: This is not my code it is part of a package in node_modules and cannot be changed. Are you sure this is an error?

Comment: Emm... [Seems like it is not even a TypeScript-compatible code](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/). I have checked the installation guide of this module and it seems like not mentioned the installation of Flow. Wish there is a better answer of this question.

Comment: Try to [follow this example](https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/react-beautiful-dnd-typescript-example)?

Comment: yea its very strange, the guy above mentioned making create-react-app Flow compatible however it seems hacky/incorrect that this should be the solution when the install page makes no mention of this step.

Comment: I found the issue it was my code somehow my IDE auto imported from the package something which did not exist without me knowing :'( I appreciate the help

Comment: "my IDE auto imported from the package" -  just happened to me and took me a while to understand what this meant.  My IDE added a bad import statement at the top of my file,  trying to import something  that didn't exist from this package as a bad autocomplete.  If you are working a similar problem, check the top of the file for imports that are unused/bad.